# What is wrong with my code to get correct GRADIENT?

Tags: c++, algorithm, rounding, floor, ceil

I have problem with rounding results. I have gradient matrix, my results are almost the same as assumed. ALMOST.

I try to use FLOOR/ROUND/CEIL but it improve nothing.

```
uint16_t t1=0,t2=0,t3=0;
float a,b,c;
uint16_t value=0;
for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
    t1 = ceil(rgbLeft->r +(floor((rgbRight->r - rgbLeft->r) * j) / (count-1)));
    t2 = ceil(rgbLeft->g +(floor((rgbRight->g - rgbLeft->g) * j) / (count-1)));
    t3 = ceil(rgbLeft->b + (floor(rgbRight->b - rgbLeft->b) * j) / (count-1));

    value = (t1 << 11) | (t2 << 5) | (t3);
    vec.push_back(value);
}
```

INPUT

count is always 16. This is sizeof matrix 16x8. I put the struct like :

```
   typedef struct{
       unsigned int r:5;
       unsigned int g:6;
       unsigned int b:5;
   }RGB;
```

rgbLeft AND rgbRight is RGB struct.
The inputs for example is 1 and 16. And i get line :

0001 0002 0003 0004 0005 0006 0007 0008 0009 000A 000B 000C 000D 000E 000F 0010

INPUT FOR THIS example is 1 16 16 1. (start top, end top, start bottom, end bottom).

First I make struct rgbLeft and rgbRight from input (1,16,16,1) (val is start top (rgbLeft), end stop(rgbRight)

```
rgb->r = (val >> 11);
rgb->g = (val >> 5);
rgb->b = (val);
```

after that i use

```
uint16_t t1=0,t2=0,t3=0;
float a,b,c;
uint16_t value=0;
for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
    t1 = ceil(rgbLeft->r +(floor((rgbRight->r - rgbLeft->r) * j) / (count-1)));
    t2 = ceil(rgbLeft->g +(floor((rgbRight->g - rgbLeft->g) * j) / (count-1)));
    t3 = ceil(rgbLeft->b + (floor(rgbRight->b - rgbLeft->b) * j) / (count-1));

    value = (t1 << 11) | (t2 << 5) | (t3);
    vec.push_back(value);
}
```

Finally I get :

0001 0002 0003 0004 0005 0006 0007 0008 0009 000A 000B 000C 000D 000E 000F 0010

0002 **0002 0003 0004** 0005 0006 0006 0007 0008 0009 000A **000A** 000B 000C 000D 000E

0004 **0004** 0005 **0005** 0006 **0006** 0007 **0007** 0008 **0008** 0009 **0009** 000A **000A** 000B 000C

0006 0006 **0006 0006** 0007 0007 **0007 0007** 0008 0008 **0008 0008** 0009 0009 **0009** 000A

0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008

000A **0009** 0009 0009 **0008 0008** 0008 0008 **0007 0007** 0007 0007 **0006 0006** 0006 0006

000C 000B **000A** 000A **0009** 0009 **0008** 0008 **0007** 0007 **0006** 0006 **0005** 0005 **0004** 0004

000E 000D 000C 000B **000A** 000A 0009 0008 **0007 0006** 0006 0005 **0004 0003 0002** 0002

0010 000F 000E 000D 000C 000B 000A 0009 0008 0007 0006 0005 0004 0003 0002 0001

But i think (??) i must have something like this:

0001 0002 0003 0004 0005 0006 0007 0008 0009 000A 000B 000C 000D 000E 000F 0010

0002 **0003 0004 0005** 0005 0006 0007 0008 0008 0009 000A **000B** 000B 000C 000D 000E

0004 **0005** 0005 **0006** 0006 **0007** 0007 **0008** 0008 **0009** 0009 **000A** 000A **000B** 000B 000C

0006 0006 **0007 0007** 0007 0007 **0008 0008** 0008 0008 **0009 0009** 0009 0009 **000A** 000A

0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008

000A **000A** 0009 0009 **0009 0009** 0008 0008 **0008 0008** 0007 0007 **0007 0007** 0006 0006

000C 000B **000B** 000A **000A** 0009 **0009** 0008 **0008** 0007 **0007** 0006 **0006** 0005 **0005** 0004

000E 000D 000C 000B **000B** 000A 0009 0008 **0008 0007** 0006 0005 **0005 0004 0003** 0002

0010 000F 000E 000D 000C 000B 000A 0009 0008 0007 0006 0005 0004 0003 0002 0001

for example input 0 0 3200 1800 is ok...

**HERE IS EXAMPLE CODE TO TEST EACH LINE :**

https://wandbox.org/permlink/bdkxrjxYtq6LHhMg

EDIT.

I change a little bit code :

```
uint8_t t1=0,t2=0,t3=0;
int a=0,b=0,c=0;
uint16_t value=0;
for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
    t1 =round(rgbLeft->r + (((floor(rgbRight->r - rgbLeft->r) * j) / (count-1))));
    t2 =round(rgbLeft->g + (((floor(rgbRight->g - rgbLeft->g) * j) / (count-1))));
    t3 =round(rgbLeft->b + (((floor(rgbRight->b - rgbLeft->b) * j) / (count-1))));


    value = (t1 << 11) | (t2 << 5) | (t3);
    vec.push_back(value);
}
```

and i get

0001 0002 0003 0004 0005 0006 0007 0008 0009 000A 000B 000C 000D 000E 000F 0010

0002 0003 0004 **0004** 0005 0006 0007 0008 0008 0009 000A 000B **000C** 000C 000D 000E

0004 0005 0005 0006 0006 0007 0007 0008 0008 0009 0009 000A 000A 000B 000B 000C

0006 0006 0007 0007 0007 0007 0008 0008 0008 0008 0009 0009 0009 0009 000A 000A

0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008 0008

000A 000A 0009 0009 0009 0009 0008 0008 0008 0008 0007 0007 0007 0007 0006 0006

000C 000B 000B 000A 000A 0009 0009 0008 0008 0007 0007 0006 0006 0005 0005 0004

000E 000D 000C **000C** 000B 000A 0009 0008 0008 0007 0006 0005 **0004** 0004 0003 0002

0010 000F 000E 000D 000C 000B 000A 0009 0008 0007 0006 0005 0004 0003 0002 0001

there are ONLY 4 POINTS DIFFRENT FROM ASSUMED !

EDIT :

tl:1

tr 16

bl 16

br 1

```
 RGB RGBtl, RGBtr, RGBbl, RGBbr;
        std::vector<uint16_t> firstColumn,lastColumn;

   valueToColorRGB(&RGBtl,tl);
   valueToColorRGB(&RGBtr,tr);
   valueToColorRGB(&RGBbl,bl);
   valueToColorRGB(&RGBbr,br);
   colorRGBtoVector(firstColumn,&RGBtl,&RGBbl,size.height);
   colorRGBtoVector(lastColumn,&RGBtr,&RGBbr,size.height);
    for (int j = 0; j < size.height; j++) {
        tl = firstColumn[j];
        tr = lastColumn[j];

        valueToColorRGB(&RGBtl,tl);
        valueToColorRGB(&RGBtr,tr);
        colorRGBtoVector2(vec3,&RGBtl,&RGBtr,size.width);
    }

valueToColorRGB(RGB *rgb, const uint16_t &val){
    rgb->r = (val >> 11);
    rgb->g = (val >> 5);
    rgb->b = (val);
}
colorRGBtoVector2(std::vector<uint16_t> &vec, RGB *rgbLeft, RGB *rgbRight, const uint16_t &count){
    uint8_t t1=0,t2=0,t3=0;
    int a=0,b=0,c=0;
    uint16_t value=0;
    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        t1 =(rgbLeft->r + ((floor(rgbRight->r - rgbLeft->r) * j) / (count-1)));
        t2 =(rgbLeft->g + ((floor(rgbRight->g - rgbLeft->g) * j) / (count-1)));
        t3 =(rgbLeft->b + ((floor(rgbRight->b - rgbLeft->b) * j) / (count-1)));


        value = (t1 << 11) | (t2 << 5) | (t3);
        vec.push_back(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give the inputs for `count` and `rgbLeft` and `rgbRight` that you're using to get these outputs?

Comment: I have no idea how to use "INPUT FOR THIS example is 1 16 16 1. (start top, end top, start bottom, end bottom)." to generate output. Please show with a `count = 16`, `rgbLeft = `#, and `rgbRight = `# for a *single* pass through the loop. Along with your actual output and expected output for the *single* pass through the loop.

Comment: important its only function to counting...

Comment: I feel like we're getting closer. You seem to be trying to show me how `rgbLeft` and `rgbRight` are generated and how the loop is called. (It's possible that the bug is in that section of code?) But if we're going to debug this loop, we're going to need the actual values of `rgbRight` and `rgbLeft` for a *single* pass that doesn't meet your expectations. To get this you should probably use the debugger, or at least print out the values of each before your code block is called, and the code blocks output from the *single* pass.

Comment: tried debugging so bar of a failing input?

Comment: yes i tried but idk why (14-2) * 1 / 15 + 2 = 2 ...

Comment: @MrSmith42 you can try here https://wandbox.org/permlink/bdkxrjxYtq6LHhMg

Comment: @JonathanMee you can try here https://wandbox.org/permlink/bdkxrjxYtq6LHhMg

Comment: @maryan I've posted an answer for you. It appears that your problem is that you were in fact not testing with the code block you posted in question above. I've attempted to explain in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56280729/2642059) but fundamentally your integer division in your testing code is giving you 0.

Comment: @maryan Looks like you're making progress. Your edit still lacks the initialization values for `count`, `rgbLeft`, and `rgbRight`. If you're looking for further help please post with *all values in the example code initialized*.

Answer (score 0):

[Your actual question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56274760/what-is-wrong-with-my-code-to-get-correct-gradient?noredirect=1#comment99173137_56274760) seems to boil down to:

> idk why (14-2) * 1 / 15 + 2 = 2

This is taken from deriving values from this you would have:

- `rgbRight`: 14U
- `rgbLeft`: 2U
- `count`: 16
- `j`: 1

Your equation in the question: `t3 = ceil(rgbLeft->b + (floor(rgbRight->b - rgbLeft->b) * j) / (count-1))` would play out in the following order:

1. `rgbRight->b - rgbLeft->b`: 12U
2. `floor(rgbRight->b - rgbLeft->b)`: 12.0
3. `floor(rgbRight->b - rgbLeft->b) * j`: 12.0
4. `count - 1`: 15
5. `(floor(rgbRight->b - rgbLeft->b) * j) / (count-1)`: 0.8
6. `rgbLeft->b + (floor(rgbRight->b - rgbLeft->b) * j) / (count-1)`: 2.8
7. `ceil(rgbLeft->b + (floor(rgbRight->b - rgbLeft->b) * j) / (count-1))`: 3.0

Finally the assignment *back* to `t3` would cast, with an ignored warning, back to **3U** *not* **2U**.

I believe what is confusing you is that [your linked tester](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bdkxrjxYtq6LHhMg) *doesn't use `double`s*: `(unsigned int)start.b + (((stop.b - start.b) * i) / (elems - 1))` which will play out in the following order:

1. `(unsigned int)start.b` : 2U
2. `stop.b - start.b`: 12U
3. `(stop.b - start.b) * i`: 12
4. `elems - 1`: 15
5. `((stop.b - start.b) * i) / (elems - 1)`: 0
6. `(unsigned int)start.b + (((stop.b - start.b) * i) / (elems - 1))`: 2U

It's key to note **5** in this list performs integer division and thus returns a **0** while **5** from the previous list performs floating point division and returns **0.8**.

Comment: in example it is working but... when i change line " t3 = ceil(rgbLeft->b + ((floor(rgbRight->b - rgbLeft->b) * j) / (count-1))); " i get  "0003 0004 0005 0006 0007 0007 0008 0009 000A 000B 000B 000C 000D 000E 000F 000F"

Comment: @maryan Could you go edit your question to include: 1) the code you're running to get that output 2) that output 3) your expected output. Please don't forget to include the initialization values of all variables used in the execution of the code. I'm not seeing those numbers when I run locally with the initialization values used above, and I'm assuming from your comment that you are.

Comment: i think i added everything.

Comment: @maryan Your initial segregation of the `colorRGBtoVector2` code was a good breaking point, because that encapsulates the functionality you are not understanding. For me to help you with this I don't need to see more of your code, I need to know what the `rgbLeft`, `rgbRight` and `count` parameter values are when `colorRGBtoVector2` returns you a value you don't expect. In the additional code you posted I still can't figure out these values because I don't have a definition of `colorRGBtoVector`. But again please don't post that function, please post the inputs to `colorRGBtoVector2`.